# Simplification of product of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

I look for a closed formula to the expression
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(e^{\frac{2ik\pi}{n}}-1\right)$$

Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Consider the polynomial $P(x)=\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}{(x-e^{\frac{2ik \pi}{n}})}$.

Comment: $e^{\frac{2i\pi k}n}$ is one of the $k$-th roots of unity, since $\left(e^{\frac{2i\pi k}n}\right)^n=e^{2i\pi k}=1^k=1$

Answer (score 3):

Consider the function
$$
f(x) = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \ldots + x^{n-1}
$$
which can be rewritten as
$$
f(x) = \frac {x^n-1}{x-1} = \frac {\displaystyle \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(x-e^{\frac {2\pi i k}n} \right)}{x-1} =\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \left(x-e^{\frac {2\pi i k}n} \right) = \\
\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^k \left(e^{\frac {2\pi i k}n}-x \right) = (-1)^n\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \left(e^{\frac {2\pi i k}n}-x \right)
$$
So what you're looking for is $(-1)^nf(1) = (-1)^n (1 + 1 + \ldots + 1) = (-1)^nn$

Comment: $f(x)$ should be $1+x+x^2+ \ldots +x^{n-1}$ and not $1+x^2+x^3+ \ldots +x^{n-1}$. It should be $(-1)^{n-1}f(1)$ instead. Also $f(1)=n$, not $n-1$.

Comment: @IvanLoh, my bad, forgot second term, thanks. Final answer should change as well. Thanks for pointing it out. You're also correct about the sign.

Comment: It is $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}{(e^{\frac{2 \pi ik}{n}}-1)}$, not $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}{(1-e^{\frac{2 \pi ik}{n}})}$

Comment: @Kaster I think it should be $(-1)^{n-1}n$, can you check that?

Answer (score 0):

The roots of $x^n-1=0$ are $e^{\frac{2k\pi i}n}$   where $k=0,1,2,\cdots,n-1$

Now, let us find the equation whose roots are $e^{\frac{2k\pi i}n}-1=y$(say)

$\implies e^{\frac{2k\pi i}n}=1+y\implies (1+y)^n-1=0$

So, $y^n+\binom n1y^{n-1}+\binom n2y^{n-2}+\cdots+\binom n{n-1}y+1-1=0 $

$\implies y^n+ny^{n-1}+\binom n2y^{n-2}+\cdots+ny=0$

$\implies y(y^{n-1}+ny^{n-2}+\binom n2y^{n-3}+\cdots+n)=0$

This $y=0$ is due to $k=0$ as $e^{\frac{2\cdot0\pi i}n}=1$

So, the roots of $y^{n-1}+ny^{n-2}+\binom n2y^{n-3}+\cdots+n=0$ are  $e^{\frac{2k\pi i}n}-1$  where  $k=1,2,\cdots,n-1$

So, using [Vieta's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VietasFormulas.html), $$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(e^{\frac{2k\pi i}n}-1)=(-1)^{n-1}(-n)=(-1)^nn$$

Comment: I think it should be $(-1)^{n-1}n$, can you check that?