# find the value $\prod_{k=0}^{9}(2+z^k)$

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $$z=\cos\left( \frac{2\pi}{10}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{10}\right)$$

Find the value
$$\prod_{k=0}^{9}(2+z^k)$$

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Could you include those efforts in your post. please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly, $z^k,0\le k\le9$ are the roots of $$z^{10}-1=0$$

Let $y=2+z^k\iff z^k=y-2\implies$  $$0=(y-2)^{10}-1=y^{10}-\binom{10}1y^9+\cdots+2^{10}-1$$

$$\implies\prod_{k=0}^9(2+z^k)=\dfrac{2^{10}-1}1$$

Comment: Oh,It's nice.+1,maybe $z^k=y-2$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376781/simplification-of-product-of-complex-numbers/376896#376896